# Why does Chrome sometimes download a PDF instead of opening it?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

When I go to certain addresses of PDF files, Chrome downloads the PDF instead of opening it using its built-in PDF viewer. The page is then blank white.

There is no problem with my Chrome settings: I try addresses of other PDF files, and Chrome behaves as expected (I have it set to use Chrome's built-in PDF viewer). But every time I try the same problematic address, Chrome downloads the PDF and then displays a blank page.

I am using Windows 10 and Chrome
`Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.

My specific problematic URL this time is [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjqu5nzuZDYAhUDbiYKHV5oCJIQFgg0MAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.seattlesymphony.org%2F~%2Fmedia%2Ffiles%2Fnotes%2Fschubert-sonata-21-b-flat.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1vXVKSqrdPLJqzb1Qt0tVS) (a Google search result).

Answer (score 189, accepted):

Basically, this happens because the website tells the browser to do it. Occasionally, it's because the website developer decides they want this behaviour, e.g. common on file sharing sites. Other times, it's because it's a default option for whatever software they're using (e.g. forum or blogging software). Sometimes it's because the site dev has no idea what they're doing.

---

## `Content-Disposition`

That's usually because the site sends a [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header in the response. Specifically, it can send either `inline` or `attachment`.

`inline` is the default if not otherwise specified, and means the browser will open the file within the browser window if it is able to.

`attachment` means to always download the file, never attempt to open it inside the browser.

---

If you open your browser's developer tools, you'll see that particular link sends the following response headers:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Schubert-Sonata-21-B-flat.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

This tells the browser to *always download* (`attachment`) the file, and to give it the default filename of `Schubert-Sonata-21-B-flat.pdf` rather than inferring it from the URL. Additionally, it does tell the browser (correctly) that it's an `application/pdf` file - but since it's an `attachment` the browser will still default to downloading.

---

### Inline handling details

When a `Content-Disposition` is inline (or unspecified), the browser will try to open the file in the default embedded viewer. This only works when the browser knows what file type it is, *and* the browser knows how to open that type.

#### Type detection

The file type can be specified by the server with a [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header. For example, the most common inline types are `text/html`, `application/javascript` and `text/css`, making up the three major parts of a modern website. You can also have more esoteric types like `application/pdf`.

Another possibility is the server has specified a `Content-Type` of [`application/octet-stream`](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/octet-stream). This is the most generic type, and it tells the browser that the file is just arbitrary data - at which point the only thing the browser can do is download it (in theory - we'll get to that).

When a `Content-Type` is not specified by the server (and sometimes even when it is), the browser can perform what is known as *sniffing* to try to guess the type by reading the file and looking for patterns.

#### Type handling

Upon receiving a file with an `inline` or unspecified disposition, the browser needs to try to open it within the browser if possible. To do this, it looks at the file type, and if it recognises the type it will try to open it. Most browsers will open any `text/` type in a simple text viewer, will try to render `text/html` as a webpage, might [open `application/json` in a special syntax-highlighted viewer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/JSON_viewer), etc..

The type `application/octet-stream` was handled specially. Since it's supposed to be the most generic type, denoting an arbitrary stream of bytes, there isn't supposed to be any handler that can apply to all files of this "type". For example, in Firefox, [this manifests as an inability to set the default handler](http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions#Unable_to_set_an_automatic_action) for `application/octet-stream`.

Some websites have also used non-standard types. I've seen `application/force-download` used - which ends up as a download because the browser does not recognise or know what else to do with the type, but does not enjoy the special handling that `application/octet-stream` does.

---

**A bit of a history lesson**

To see how PDFs are handled, we can delve a bit into web history. See, in the past, browsers had no idea what a PDF is. So they could not open it. But we've seen PDFs being opened in browsers long before built-in PDF viewers were a thing, so how did that work?

It used to be possible to extend browser functionality with far more control than what you can do with limited extensions/addons these days. Those were most generically known as [*plugins*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)). In Internet Explorer, they were ActiveX controls; in Mozilla Firefox and later Google Chrome they were NPAPI plugins. These plugins were capable of doing everything any other program could, and could additionally register themselves as a handler for a specific file type that might be otherwise unrecognised by the browser. (Incidentally, this was later found to be a huge security risk and support for these powerful plugins was gradually dropped...)

In the days of plugins, you would go and install Adobe Acrobat Reader, which would then install an ActiveX or NPAPI plugin that would register the `application/pdf` MIME type and tell the browser to open those types inline using the plugin.

Of course, after a number of security and performance issues caused by these plugins, the major browser vendors decided to incorporate their own PDF viewers while phasing out support for most plugins. The only one we still see is Adobe Shockwave Flash, which handles `application/x-shockwave-flash`.

There's actually still some leftover controls for this, e.g. in Firefox the `Preview in Firefox` option still exists:

[image: Screenshot of option]

In the past, this would have allowed the choice between multiple plugins that registered that type. For example, the list of registered types for Flash:

[image: Screenshot of registered types]

Those days were also before a lot of the media support that came with HTML5. It wasn't just PDFs - your browser would have no idea how to handle a MP4 container or H.264 video, no idea how to play a MP3 file, etc., etc.. You would see plugins provided by media players like VLC or even Windows Media Player, or websites would embed a media player built in Flash.

Comment: On occasion it also happens when the server sets `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` but that's a lot less common these days.

Comment: The reason why the values "inline" and "attachment" are used is because Content-Disposition was originally specified for MIME email, where those values are a lot more appropriate :)

Comment: @hobbs: Almost a case study in domain-specific terminology in reusable technology when something more abstract will do ^_^

Answer (score 24):

I found an explanation. According to an [answer I found](https://superuser.com/a/515622/853866), it appears that Chrome will download a PDF if the MIME content type is set not to `application/pdf` but rather an "incorrect or generic MIME type", `application/octet-stream`.

[Furthermore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types), "Most web servers send unknown-type resources using the default `application/octet-stream` MIME type. For security reasons, most browsers do not allow setting a custom default action for such resources, forcing the user to store it to disk to use it."

Comment: Indeed - this logic overrides content disposition and is thus important to remember.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It doesn't so much *override* the disposition as it gives the browser a type it can't do anything with (barring sniffing) other than save to disk. Granted, the visible effect is the same.

Comment: @Bob: Okay yeah that's a fair interpretation

Answer (score 23):

This is due to the [HTTP `Content-Disposition` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) specifying that the file is an *attachment*. This instructs the browser to download the file, rather than to open it directly.

[There is a Chrome add-on that can override this behavior.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-forcedownload-blocker/ojbkmmcompidaghfnodmbeiankbbfckl?hl=en) The following image is from the Firefox developer tools:

[image: HTTP request as seen in the Firefox development tools]

Comment: May I ask if there is also a similar Firefox add-on?

Comment: @davyjones You may. So that you don't have to ask whether there is a Firefox add-on, [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/bypass-forced-download/) one is.

Comment: That plugin doesn't appear to work anymore

Comment: This other extension appears to work: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-pdf-download/ikhahkidgnljlniknmendeflkdlfhonj