# How can I force my browser to view PDF files in-browser instead of downloading them?

Tags: browser, pdf, download

At some point (I think quite recently, but I'm not sure), [Nature](https://www.nature.com) started forcing the browser to download the PDF files for papers, instead of opening them in the browser. How can I force the browser to stop this behaviour, and open PDF links in the browser?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are apparently several ways in which the website can try to force your web browser to download a given file instead of opening it in-window. One way in which this can happen (sending the attribute `Content-Disposition: attachment` instead of `inline` in the http header of the response) has already been handled in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1277819/why-does-chrome-sometimes-download-a-pdf-instead-of-opening-it).

What Nature is currently doing is including a `download` attribute in the `a` link tag that goes to the pdf. This can be diagnosed (in Google Chrome) by right-clicking the link and looking at the tag itself in the element viewer:

[image]

This can be fixed by using a suitable userscript to remove this attribute using a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) for Google Chrome or [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Firefox.

This is a simple userscript that will do it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     View Nature pdfs in-browser
// @include  https://www.nature.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

/*--- Use the jQuery contains selector to find content to remove.
    Beware that not all whitespace is as it appears.
*/

var allLinks, thisLink;
allLinks = document.evaluate(
    '//a[@download]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
    null);
for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.snapshotLength; i++) {
    thisLink = allLinks.snapshotItem(i);
    thisLink.removeAttribute('download');
}
```