# How do I tell Chrome to open a pdf in Mac Preview instead of in-line?

Tags: mac, google-chrome, pdf, preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable automatic opening of PDF files in chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/107700/how-to-disable-automatic-opening-of-pdf-files-in-chrome)

I've looked at the answers to this question: [How to disable automatic opening of PDF files in chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/107700/how-to-disable-automatic-opening-of-pdf-files-in-chrome), but they do not work.  If I click a pdf file, it opens in the browser, it no longer let's me open the file in preview, or even download the file!  If I do save-as it tries to  save a file like this: jxb.erq386.full.pdf+html

This was working until this morning.  I've tried resetting

Comment: Even if the answers did not work, it is a duplicate. And on a Q&A site we need everything Q to be unique, and collect all its A's into one place. Sorry, still voting to close. (Also, apparently *something* changed in your set up, but you did not tell us *what* might have changed.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable automatic opening of PDF files in chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/107700/how-to-disable-automatic-opening-of-pdf-files-in-chrome) or [Stop PDFs from displaying inside Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/30850/stop-pdfs-from-displaying-inside-google-chrome)