# Chrome 9: how to save PDF?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Chrome natively displays PDFs within the browser.  Sometimes, I want to save a copy of the displayed PDF locally on my drive.  How do I do that?  I tried doing "Save Page as ..." but that didn't work.

Comment: It should work. Just tested it on my machine. Both Chrome 8 and 9, on Mac, with a PDF, both using *File » Save Page as...* and right-click *» Save As...* -- Have you tried another PDF document, if maybe the web server is not available right now, or it's an issue with a specific document? What OS do you use?

Comment: You are right.  Sorry, I must have done something wrong the 10 previous times I attempted it.

Comment: Sarcasm, or does it work all of a sudden?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/107700/how-to-disable-automatic-opening-of-pdf-files-in-chrome-closed Try: "Open chrome://plugins/ in the browser and disable the PDF Viewer plugin." hth

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  sorry wasn't trying to be sarcastic.  It works.

Comment: @Daniel Beck:  this is not working consistently.  I open http://someserver/doc.pdf.  Chrome displays the PDF.  I right click the center of the PDF doc and I see "Save as".  I click that option and nothing happens.  Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Is it document-dependent? If yes, please provide the URL of one such document.

Answer (score 2):

You can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on a Mac).

Comment: It's the shortcut for the *Save Page As...* menu entry which he mentioned didn't work.

Comment: I'm on the Windows version and it works fine when there's no menu entry to save it.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot , You have to install an extension such as https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/kpdjmbiefanbdgnkcikhllpmjnnllbbc

Comment: He wants to save displayed PDFs. Not save web pages *as* PDF.