# How to disable Adobe Pdf in chrome or make it work properly

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Chrome opens all the pdf files like this (latest ver). I can't find where to disable Adobe PDFviewer in Chrome or replace it with the default Chrome viewer.

[image: screen]

Comment: This question is asking the opposite but there will be some insight for what you want.....https://superuser.com/questions/735751/open-pdfs-in-adobe-instead-of-in-google-chrome?rq=1

Comment: the problem was with the reverso translator extension, without it everything works fine