# Google Chrome - How can I set in which app the downloaded files are opened?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I download the file to some location in Google Chrome (version 71.0.3578.98). Now I open the file from chrome (from the download bar or from the download manager). Where can I set the associated app? Or at least force the browser to follow the OS default setting?

EDIT: I checked that with pdf files, it doesť work.

Comment: It should use OS default. What file type is that?

Comment: @gronostaj It doesn't work for me with pdf files.

Comment: The link for https://superuser.com/questions/724203/how-to-automatically-open-saved-pdfs-in-system-viewer-on-chrome is just a bit obsolete;  see https://www.lifewire.com/disable-chrome-extensions-and-plugins-4136252 for information on using chrome://settings/content and chrome://extensions . Chrome will only open file types for which it has an installed and enabled plugin or extension.

Comment: @Debra The problem is to enable both: open the pdf in the browser and open the downloaded file in the default system app at the same time.