# How can I improve the PDF viewer in Chrome x64

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I recently switch to Chrome x64 and found that the old Sumatra PDF plug-in no longer worked. It uses the old Netscape API which is being removed from Chrome, so even if it were ported to x64 it wouldn't work.

I view a lot of technical documents, datasheets and the like. Functions like having the index (bookmarks in PDF language) displayed at the side for easier navigation are essential. Many documents have hundreds of pages and are very difficult to navigate in the standard Chrome viewer.

Without having to download every document and open it externally, how I can view PDFs comfortably and efficiently in Chrome x64?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop PDFs from displaying inside Google Chrome](http://superuser.com/questions/30850/stop-pdfs-from-displaying-inside-google-chrome)

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to modify the way their Chrome plugin works to add your chosen functionality, so instead why not just set Chrome to use an external PDF viewer?  (See answers on question marked as duplicate regarding how to do that).

Comment: My requirement is specifically to have the PDF displayed in the browser. I don't want to download it and open a new window, that would break my workflow and create extra unnecessary work.

Comment: What you're looking for is this: [PDF Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/details?hl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try installing a PDF extension from the Chrome store. That way you don't have to worry about 64 bit issues. In particular, [PDF Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdf-viewer/oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm?hl=en-US) seems to give the functionality that you asked for (indexing) under the sidebar and is fast like Sumatra PDF. If that is not to your liking there are also others like Notable PDF, but I haven't tried that so I can't speak to whether it has the functionality that meets your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. It's a vast improvement.

Comment: Nice,  I'm glad that helped.